# This document does not exist, it will not appear in queries or snapshots? Cloud Firestore

Tags: node.js, database, nosql, google-admin-sdk, google-cloud-firestore

I'm quite new to Cloud Firestore (aren't we all?) and I've added some data to my db using the admin SDK in Node.js. It shows up on the console, but under the doc it says "This document does not exist, it will not appear in queries or snapshots." I'm not sure why this is? Here's a screenshot:[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key thing to realize is that just because you create a document at `root_collection > root_doc > sub_collection > sub_doc` does not mean there is actually a document at `root_collection > root_doc`.

So in order to show you the documents under `... > Events > 10-12-2017 > Phase Data`, the console is showing `10-12-2017` as if it was a document, but it's letting you know that there is actually no document at that location. So if you do a query for the documents under `... > Events`, `10-12-2017` will not show up.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I've decided to just cross back over to the realtime database (yeah i gave up), but ill mark you as correct!

Comment: Sorry to hear that! If you feel like sharing feedback on what caused you to give up or how our docs / examples / console could be more helpful, feel free to drop me a line at michael@firebase.com. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Michael. I asked a similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47043651/this-document-does-not-exist-and-will-not-appear-in-queries-or-snapshots-but-id. If you have some time, could you take a look? We have several collections that are structured identically but warning is only being shown for some.

Comment: @MichaelLehenbauer is there any way to avoid creating a virtual doc and **actually** create `root_doc` dynamically when running the code that creates `root_collection > root_doc > sub_collection > sub_doc`

Comment: @MichaelLehenbauer I would love to know the answer to Jaywaa's question too

Comment: I don't think the console lets you create 2 documents at once with a single UI action...  but it's possible via the SDKs to do a batch write of both the "parent" doc and the "child" doc to create them simultaneously.  They will still be independent and could be deleted separately, etc. though.

Comment: Further, @MichaelLehenbauer , the batched writes still consider each of the internal operations individually against your firebase billing!!!

Comment: Can anyone answer @Jaywaa 's question? Is there a way to create non-virtual docs in between, in a way similar to Unix's `mkdirs`()?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the answer you all are looking for:
When you create a document like:

```
let ref = Firestore.firestore().collection("users").document().collection("data")
```

you aren't creating an actual location for that document with the auto-generated id.
Rather, add an empty field as so:

```
let tempRef = Firestore.firestore().collection("users").addDocument(data: ["dummy":"text"])
let id = ref.documentId
let ref = Firestore.firestore.collection("users").document(id).collection("data")
```

I tried it out and works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Based on suggestion by @rithvik-ravikumar by using Firestore batch (Swift version):

First we creating new document under `/users/:id/issues` and updating attribute `updatedAt` on `/users/:id` to make it "queryable".

```swift
func saveInBatch() {

   let db = Firestore.firestore()
   
   var issueReportData: [String: Any] = [:] // Some data you want to store.
   
   let batch = db.batch()
   let userDocRef = db.collection("users").document("_firebase_user_id_goes_here_")
   let issueDocRef = userDocRef.collection("issues").document() // This will be a new document.

   // This is needed in order to make document "queryable".
   batch.setData(["updatedAt": FieldValue.serverTimestamp()], forDocument: userDocRef)
   batch.setData(issueReportData, forDocument: issueDocRef)

   batch.commit() { err in
       if let err = err {
           print("Error writing batch \(err)")
       } else {
           print("Batch write succeeded.")
       }
   }
}
```

Now we can fetch documents at `/users` path.

```swift
func fetchUsers() {
   let db = Firestore.firestore()
   db.collection("users").getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
      if let err = err {
         print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
      } else {
         debugPrint("Found \(querySnapshot!.documents.count) documents")
         for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
            let data = document.data()
            print("\(document.documentID) => \(data)")
         }
      }
   }
}
```