# How to create a chain path in Firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am writing a cloud function for creating a path/doc like this:

```
transaction.create(db.collection('collect1/doc1/collect2').doc(), {current: "simulator"})
```

There was no error or anything. The doc get created successfully as well as the collection, but the `doc1` displays in italic style with gray color text and has description like this:
`This document does not exist, it will not appear in queries or snapshots`

Is there another way which I can achieve creating path as above without getting this result?

[image]

Comment: get rid of `current: "simulator"` ?

Comment: @RonnieRoyston no no. current: "simulator" is just an object which put in the collect2. it is not a problem. even deleting that line has no problem.

Comment: A document needs to have at least one field for it to exist. So add a field. Any field. Just make one up. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47043651/this-document-does-not-exist-and-will-not-appear-in-queries-or-snapshots-but-id

Comment: @RonnieRoyston this is the problem. I am trying to make sure while creating the path, the new document also has field, but can't figure out.

Comment: you need to `.set.` or `.update`? See https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#transactions

Comment: are you trying to make a subCollection?

Comment: It'll be best if you share a complete screenshot of your Firestore. Is that random doc ID generated by `.doc()` or is it the parent document ID? Because you have `doc1` hard-coded in your code. Also please share the actual code that you are running.