# No documents found in the database, even though I have

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

[This is what collection of 'users' looks like (created during sign up of the user)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pa1Cq.png)

[This is what collection of 'test' looks like (manually created in the firestore firebase console)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8fta.png)

[This is the code as well as the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZMQng.png)

It was returning document of ID if I am manually created the collection in the firebase console, but if not its not returning any or it says No document found even though there is.

I already try some of the solution I found but none of them are working.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow.  In order to entice anyone to assit you and to meet the guidelines on this site, you need to update your question to include the code you are talking about, a picture of the code is not acceptable, and is unable to by copy and pasted to test the issue, so please update your question if you would like some help.  You said you tried some things, show what you tried.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! I recommend you to check this question which seems similar case as yours https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47043651/this-document-does-not-exist-and-will-not-appear-in-queries-or-snapshots-but-id and check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for your reference.

Comment: The document IDs in your first screenshot are in italics, which means that there is no actual document with that ID and the console merely shows that value because there are collections *under* the document. So a `getDocuments()` call will not return those italic IDs, because they are not actually documents. --- You will have to create those documents to get them back from the API.