# How can i delete empty docs from the Cloud firestore?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

So i have some docs that say: "This document does not exist. It will not appear in queries or snapshots", and i want to delete them using Javascript.
Can anyone explain me how i can access them and delete them?

Answer (score 1):

You can't delete it, because it doesn't exist.

You'll notice that the ID of the document appears in italics.  That, and the message you're seeing, indicate that there is no document with the ID you selected.  The reason why it appears is because it has subcollections nested under it.  The console shows these documents so that you can click through and see the nested subcollections (otherwise, they would be completely invisible to you in the console).

See also:

- [This document does not exist and will not appear in queries or snapshots, but identically structured document works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47043651/this-document-does-not-exist-and-will-not-appear-in-queries-or-snapshots-but-id)
- [This document does not exist, it will not appear in queries or snapshots? Cloud Firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46821241/this-document-does-not-exist-it-will-not-appear-in-queries-or-snapshots-cloud)

If you were expecting the deletion of that document to also delete the subcollections, that's not going to happen with a simple document delete.  You will have to write code to delete all the documents in all the subcollections as well.

See also:

- [Delete a Document with all Subcollections and Nested Subcollections in Firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49286764/delete-a-document-with-all-subcollections-and-nested-subcollections-in-firestore)